# Kali linux VM VBOX guest additions, Terminal: permission denied

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine

i'm using kali linux 64bit 2016.2 on virtualbox. I need drag and drop option. I downloanded the guest additions and tried to install it. I used different commands and all of them didn't work. check the screen:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before installing the Virtualbox guest additions you need to run:

```
apt-get install build-essentialmodule-assistant
```

Then the third command you tried (sh ....) should work.

If that doesn't work you can install the guest additions via apt-get.  I believe the correct command is:

```
apt-get install virtualbox-ose-guest-utils
```

I have done this with other Linux distributions before (never Kali) and found the later to be more reliable than the Virtualbox guest additions CD.

Comment: what do you mean "do not have sudo installed" ? is sudo an installable package?

Comment: Sorry, I have to edit my answer.  That part of the answer was flat out dumb. As you are running as root there is no need for sudo regardless.  Sorry again, I'll edit it right now.

Comment: i got that error when i try E: Unable to locate package build-essentialmodule-assistant

Answer (score 2):

Have the same problem here, but I using Debian instead of Kali (yeah I know Kali is Debian derivative).
So here step that I have to take:

```
# apt-get install build-essential module-assistant
# bash ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Still got an error here, and then I see [Rocks Storm's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1251107) and then I install `make` and kernel header according to my architecture (which is `amd-64`).

```
# uname -r
4.9.0.9-amd64
# apt-get install make linux-headers-amd-64 -y
```

And then try to install guest additions again:

```
# bash ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Done. And then restart your virtual machine.